# Sending a Boxed trait between threads

Tags: rust

I've been playing with rust and I was doing a very silly program which combined traits, structs, some silly concurrency and generics. Everything was quite understandable for me until I faced some problems when sending a trait between threads.

Firs of all, at one point a realized I needed a vector of Boxed Animals in order to store the different elements that comply with the Animal trait, ok, I get that because the trait is an abstraction of some other particular structs which can vary in "size" etc, so we have to store them in the heap.
But then the first weird point for me was that because I had to use a Box to store the traits, then I had to implement my trait for the Boxed trait also (see (*1) on the code comments).

Once I did that, the program was correct for the compiler, but I ran into some problems at runtime that I don't understand.
The error that I'm getting is:

```
thread '<unknown>' has overflowed its stack
fatal runtime error: stack overflow
[1]    4175 abort (core dumped)  cargo run
```

The code is:

```
use std::thread;
use std::sync::mpsc::{Sender};
use std::sync::mpsc;
use std::time;

trait Animal {
    fn poop(&self) -> Poop;
}

#[derive(Debug)]
enum Weight {
    VeryLight,
    Light,
    Medium,
    Heavy,
    SuperHeavy,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Poop {
    shape: String,
    weight: Weight,
}

struct Wombat;

impl Animal for Wombat {
    fn poop(&self) -> Poop {
        Poop {
            shape: "cubic".to_string(),
            weight: Weight::Light,
        }
    }
}

struct Cat;

impl Animal for Cat {
    fn poop(&self) -> Poop {
        Poop {
            shape: "cylindrical".to_string(),
            weight: Weight::VeryLight,
        }
    }
}

// (*1) This seemed weird for me and I'm not sure the 
// impl es correct
impl Animal for Box<dyn Animal + Send> {
    fn poop(&self) -> Poop {
        let t: &dyn Animal = self;
        // self.poop()
        t.poop()

    }
}

fn feed_animal<T> (a: T, tx: Sender<String>)
    where T: Animal + Send + 'static {
    
    thread::spawn(move || {
        thread::sleep(time::Duration::from_secs(2));
        tx.send(format!("{:?}", a.poop()))
    });
}

fn main() {
    let mut animals: Vec<Box<dyn Animal + Send>> = Vec::new();
    animals.push(Box::new(Wombat));
    animals.push(Box::new(Cat));
    
    let (tx, rx) = mpsc::channel();

    for a in animals {
        let txi = tx.clone();
        feed_animal(a, txi);
    }

    drop(tx);

    for r in rx {
        println!("The animal just pooped: {:?}", r);
    }
}
```

I'm a little lost with the error message honestly. Usually when I see this kind of error in some other programing languages is due to an infinite loop that will overflow the stack, but in this case I guess there must be some error in the way I "send" the Boxed trait to the child thread that makes rust handle the child thread stack memory badly at runtime.. I'm not sure.

Any hint to the right direction will be very welcomed.
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have changed your code a little bit. You can check it using this [playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=fb2ac23ffc1e3a676df6a2add351d78c).

I think you made one mistake in this function signature,

```
fn feed_animal<T> (a: T, tx: Sender<String>)
    where T: Animal + Send + 'static {
}
```

where `a` should be `Box<T>`, therefore you wouldn't need to implement `Animal` for `Box<dyn Animal + Send>`.

Code after some editing is shown below.

```
use std::thread;
use std::sync::mpsc::{Sender};
use std::sync::mpsc;
use std::time;

trait Animal {
    fn poop(&self) -> Poop;
}

#[derive(Debug)]
enum Weight {
    VeryLight,
    Light,
    Medium,
    Heavy,
    SuperHeavy,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Poop {
    shape: String,
    weight: Weight,
}

struct Wombat;

impl Animal for Wombat {
    fn poop(&self) -> Poop {
        Poop {
            shape: "cubic".to_string(),
            weight: Weight::Light,
        }
    }
}

struct Cat;

impl Animal for Cat {
    fn poop(&self) -> Poop {
        Poop {
            shape: "cylindrical".to_string(),
            weight: Weight::VeryLight,
        }
    }
}

fn feed_animal<T: ?Sized> (a: Box<T>, tx: Sender<String>)
    where T: Animal + Send + 'static {
    
    thread::spawn(move || {
        thread::sleep(time::Duration::from_secs(2));
        tx.send(format!("{:?}", a.poop()))
    });
}

fn main() {
    let mut animals: Vec<Box<dyn Animal + Send>> = Vec::new();
    animals.push(Box::new(Wombat{}));
    animals.push(Box::new(Cat{}));
    
    let (tx, rx) = mpsc::channel();

    for a in animals {
        let txi = tx.clone();
        feed_animal(a, txi);
    }

    for r in rx {
        println!("The animal just pooped: {:?}", r);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, I see your point, did not think about this option. But, is this "idiomatic" Rust? What would be the best option of the two? Because, for example, my reasoning when defining the "feed_animal" function is.. "I want to receive as input a type T which complies with the Animal trait"; that's my specification on the code. But, would the reasoning be.. "ok, I know Animal is a trait, therefore I know I have to receive as input a Box<T> where T complies with the Animal trait". What would be more correct/idiomatic?

Comment: What you want to do is to feed animals in new threads and having their poop send back to main thread. Then, I think making `a` a `Box<T>` makes more sense.
You can think of Box as a pointer for heap allocation that 1) provides ownership of the allocation, 2) drop the allocation when Box goes out of scope and 3) ensure fixed size.
In feed_animal(), when the Box<T> is moved to a new thread, the heap allocation ownership of T is also moved to the new thread. This is because Box provides ownership for T. You can verify this by using a after calling feed_animal in the for loop.

Answer (score 2):

Let's focus on this code:

```rust
impl Animal for Box<dyn Animal + Send> {
    fn poop(&self) -> Poop {
        let t: &dyn Animal = self;
        // self.poop()
        t.poop()

    }
}
```

Here, we get `self` of type `&Box<dyn Animal + Send>`, cast it to `&dyn Animal`, and make it `poop`.

I believe you were confused by the levels of indirection, and the presence of an additional `&` in particular. By casting `Box<dyn Animal + Send>` to `dyn Animal`, you get a dynamicised version of the `Box`. Later on, you call `poop` on that dynamicised version, which makes the function unintentionally recursive.

The correct code is

```rust
let t: &dyn Animal = &**self;
```

By the way, there are tools to get a stack trace in case of problems. One such solution, a multi-purpose one, is to run `valgrind target/debug/your-binary`.

Comment: So let's see if I understood correctly then. The &** makes reference to:
*) Get the value of the Box (which is a pointer to the heap)
*) Get the value of the pointer pointing to the heap (which points to an Animal)
&) Get the reference to the animal stored in the heap

Is that correct?